# Softwares not installing in windows 8

Tags: windows, installation

I am having a strange problem with windows 8. I am not able to install a lot of softwares like VmWare itunes etc on it. After I click on the installer, the UAC pops up. When I click run, nothing happens! Help me please.

Comment: I had no problem installing these applications.  You will need to provide more information in order to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the feature called .net framework 3.5 is not activated in your system try to insert windows installation media and enter the following as administrator in the command prompt

**dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /SourceC:\sxs /LimitAccess**

Note you have to change the path "C:" to your inserted media's drive path

For more information you can refer this website: http://blogs.technet.com/b/aviraj/archive/2012/08/04/windows-8-enable-net-framework-3-5-includes-net-2-0-and-3-0-i-e-netfx3-feature-in-online-amp-offline-mode.aspx